# Execute a remote bash script locally

Tags: bash, ssh, scripting, remote

I've seen that it's possible to run scripts stored locally on a remote server eg.:
run a command:

```
ssh USER@HOST 'COMMAND'
```

run a script

```
ssh root@192.168.1.1 'bash -s' < script.sh
```

What about doing it on the oppisite way?

**Is it possible to get a script stored on a remote server and execute it locally?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you essentially can read the script file in:

```
bash -c "$( ssh user@remote_host "cat /path/to/script.sh" )"
```

Worked well with this minimal thing:

```
#!/bin/bash
seq 1 10
```

Comment: Yes - rolled back the suggested edit.

Comment: Noted. :) comment deleted.